# Compiling error when trying to run code from github Failed to execute / Compilation failure

Tags: java, heroku

```
Error:    https://pastebin.com/uaGPJz6N
```

When in my own IDE, I set the project level to 8, which works fine. Once i run the code from my repo to a hosting service called Heroku, it runs the project on 1.5. Any idea how i change this?

```
pom.xml:    https://pastebin.com/LS9EicPt
```

Any help is appreciated as most likely something ive missed. thanks :)

Comment: you can add images and code direct here. It's easier to understand your problem.

Comment: Please provide what have you tried by adding your code and never a screenshot and error stack trace. Do refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

According to [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support) they use Java 8 by default.

> You can specify a Java version by adding a file called `system.properties` to your application.
>
> Set a property java.runtime.version in the file:
>
> `java.runtime.version=11`
>
> Accepted major version values are 1.7, 1.8, 11, 12, 13 and 14. Because the default is 1.8, you don’t need this file if you would like to use Java 8.

Also, in your `pom.xml` file you seem to incorrectly setup the Java version, it should be (not `maven.compiler.testTarget`):

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>
```